# Python проверить содержимое папок

Tags: python

Как проверить, что содержится в папке, файлы или другие папки?
Для `os.path.isfile`  нужно указывать название файла. Мне это не надо.
Просто проверить, что внутри,файлы или папки.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Что если внутри директории и файлы и папки ?

Comment: Такого там не будет. Это точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополню ответ icYFTL. Нет необходимости проходить по всему генератору, при таком подходе вы обходите все папки рекурсивно, что не требуется в рамках задачи, и конечно может вызвать проблемы с производительностью.

```
import os

test = os.walk('/path')
path, dirs, files = next(test)
if files:   print('file')
if dirs:    print('folder')
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `os.walk()`

```
import os

for address, dirs, files in os.walk('<YOUR_PATH_TO_DIR>'):
   if files:
      print(f'In {address} exists files')
   if dirs:
      print(f'In {address} exists dirs')
```

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение на основе ответа выше

```
def check_is_dir_files(data):
    inside_folders=None
    inside_files=None
    for dirs, folder, files in os.walk(data):
        inside_folders=folder
        inside_files=files
        break
print(inside_folders)
print(inside_files)
```